# Does it make sense to increase sample count using bootstrapping? Then, how can achieve it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

I have 15 samples and it's somewhat small to do regression analysis.

Someone told that increasing sample count using bootstrapping technique will make my data more statistically meaningful. So I tried.

What I first tried was making my sample count from 15 to 1000 through 'resample' funtion from scikit-learn in Python.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html

But when I see the source code of 'resample' function, there seems to be nothing about bootstrapping.

So, here are my questions.

Q1: Resampling 15 samples to 1000 using Bootstrapping technique is statistically meaningful?

Q2: If it is, how can achieve it in Python environment?

Thanks.

Comment: "Bootstrapping" or a numpy.random.sample called multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. While the bootstrap itself is a widely used and statistically valid technique, 15 samples is probably too small to do anything useful.

There might be domain specific reasons why you feel that the 15 samples are representative of the population you are interested in. In that case, you could use the bootstrap. One thing you might want to think about is combining the bootstrap with variations in the data. i.e. Every time the data is resamples, add some noise to the new data and then append it to the original dataset.

This is a great resource to learn about the bootstrap technique and its variations:
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/lectures/08-bootstrap/lecture-08.pdf

Q2. You're on the right track with the sklearn function. As mentioned in the 
documentation, the resample function implements one step of the bootstrap.

Basically what you need to do is to run a loop that calls the resample function on your original data and appends it to a new DataFrame until the size of the new DataFrame is 1000. Note: the new DataFrame should also contain the original data.

The resample function will return a randomly selected subset of your data. The number of observations in the random subset is equal to the value of n_samples. For example, if you set n_samples=10, then 10 data points are returned by the replace function. If you set n_samples=15, then resample will return the entire dataset each time.

Another parameter you need to consider is replace. If replace is True, then data points from your original data can be repeated in the subset returned by replace. If replace is False, then each data point in your original data can only appear once in the subset.

The choices to these parameters will depend on the data you have, but a reasonable approach is probably to set n_samples < 15 and replace=True to increase variations in the data returned by resample.